# jQuery apply functionality only to class and parent elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following list:

```
<ul>
<li class="topCurrent">One
    <ul>
        <li>One-1
            <ul>
                 <li>One-1.1
                     <ul>
                         <li class="current">One-1.1.1
                             <ul>
                                 <li>One-1.1.1.1</li>
                                 <li>One-1.1.1.2</li>
                                 <li>One-1.1.1.3</li>
                             </ul>
                         </li>
                         <li>One-1.1.2</li>
                     </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li>One-1.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>One-2</li>
        <li>One-3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Two
    <ul>
        <li>Two-1</li>
        <li>Two-2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Using the following jQuery:

```
$("ul li ul").hide();

$("ul li").hoverIntent(
    function(){
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown('fast');
    },
    function(){
       $(this).children('ul').slideUp('fast');
    }
);
```

What this does is hide all of the ul below the top level ul until there is a hover over it.

What I would like to do is this:

If an li has a `class="current"` I would like that structure to be open up until the point that current is hit. It would still allow the ul below it to be displayed on a hover, as well as any other ul's, but at no point would the parents of `class="current"` be hidden.

Suggestions? This problem has been driving me crazy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should be all you need:

```
$("ul li:not(:has(li.current))")
   .find("ul").hide().end() // Hide all other ULs
   .hoverIntent(
        function(){
            $(this).children('ul').slideDown('fast');
        },
        function(){
           $(this).children('ul').slideUp('fast');
        }
    );
```

This will keep the hover functionality from applying to any LI that has an `li.current` as a child.

[Here is a demo](http://jsbin.com/ufebu3) (using hover instead of hoverIntent for ease of demoing).

Answer (score 0):

Just change your hoverIntent call to the following:

```
$("ul li").hoverIntent(
    function(){
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown('fast');
    },
    function(){
       $(this).children('ul').not($('.current').parents()).slideUp('fast');
    }
);
```

P.S. Should mention that my answer refs [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver)'s answer when [you asked this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854061/display-hidden-li-based-on-class).
P.P.S. Wish my debug time had been reduced by your referencing that post and not changing the class name.